# How does Metropolis acceptance rate vary with the number of dimensions?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Intuitively, if I want to update two parameters in one step, I have to come up with a proposal that are good for both parameters. Assuming that the parameters are independent, is it correct to demonstrate this intuition by saying the following?

> if the probability of accepting the proposal for one parameter is X,
>   then the probability of accepting the proposal for two parameters is
>   lower at $X^2$

Based on my experience running MCMC I have a hunch that this statement is not mathematically correct (i.e. the probability of accepting for two parameters can't be as low as $X^2$), but I cannot figure out why mathematically.

Comment: The question does not make much sense to me: what is the meaning of independence of two parameters in this MH context? how can you marginalise the MH algorithm to accept only one parameter? Please produce an illustration.

Comment: My apology -- I indeed asked this in haste and it's a really low effort question. I'll think about this more carefully and come up with a concrete example.